# How to define a variable on Debian 10 command line?

Tags: debian, terminal

I am defining a variable on Debian 10 command line but getting the error.

Do anyone know how can I do that?

[image]

Thank you,

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shells are weird in that you're not allowed to have whitespace around the `=`.

```
count=10
```

should work. (Otherwise, the shell thinks you're trying to call a program named `count` with parameters `=` and `10`.)

(PS: copy-pasting the line and error message is more useful than posting a screenshot. Our colleagues that use screen readers due to visual impairment, for example, had no chance to help you with your question because they can't tell what you did and what the error was.)